# python read text file and add strings and create new txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a txt file with pipe delimiter like below:

```
    a|b|c|d|e|f
    d|f|g|h|j|k
```

i want to read the values from the txt file and assign some column names like below

```
      data1 = index(1)
      data2 = index(2)
      data3 = index(3)
      data4 = index(4)
      data5 = index(5)
      data6 = index(7)
      data7 = "xyz"
      data8 = "hgf"
      data9 = "opi"
```

Now i want to write everything into new text file like below:
data8|data9|data2|data3|data1|data5|data6|data4|data7|

Any help is more appreciated.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask]( https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to implement this feature” is not a Stack Overflow issue.

Answer (score 0):

To write to a file, all you have to do is open one, write, then close

```
f = open("name.txt", "w")
f.write(data8 + '|')
f.write(data9 + '|')
f.write(data2 + '|')
f.write(data3 + '|')
f.write(data1 + '|')
f.write(data6 + '|')
f.write(data4 + '|')
f.write(data7 + '|')
f.close()
```

The file will be created in the directory where you ran the program.
If you want to write data not in string format, use str() around the data.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. Before writing i want to read the file and assign that to variables and then i have to write to another file. Please advise how to read and assign that to values.

Comment: Instead of opening the .txt file for writing, open it for reading ('r' instead of 'w'), then use f.read(x) to read the next x characters in the file. Don't forget about the pipeline spaces or newline characters.

Comment: I want to read based on index on a pipe delimiter file and assign column names to that file.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a list for keeping the values

Example:

```
#after reading the file - output "a|b|c|d"
out = "a|b|c|d"
out = out.split("|") #will output ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
#here you can change the values of the list
#re-creating string with separators

for i in range(0, len(out) * 2, 2):
    out.insert(i, "|")

out = "".join(out)
```

That should give you the desired output.
to open files, do this  `file = open("filename.ext", "(w) for write or (r) for read only")`, then to write do `file.write("text")`, to read all at once: `file.read()` and to get the lines do `file.readlines(amount of lines to read - leave blank for all lines)`. Hopefully this can be helpful.

Comment: I have a txt file with 1000 rows. I want to read all the rows using index and assign a column name to that.After that i want to swap and add extra strings to that and write into a separate file.

Comment: For that, you can use the ```index``` method of a list (using readlines()) as mentioned above, and to make a separate line after the text, just add ```\n``` to the end of the string, so it is restored in separate lines. You can facilitate the swapping before re-writing the file. The variables that you specified can be replaced with a Dict, the variables being the Dict keys.